# Decorating a Leaflet map with borders and texts inside

Tags: leaflet

I'm using Leaflet to create my webmaps, and wondered if there is any way to decorate it by inserting borders, texts inside, legend, etc.

Comment: There is. You can use css as you would with any other html element. I suggest you examine the page in chrome dev tools or similar, to see how a leaflet map is created.

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet uses simply a HTML div element for its map, you can add other elements to the page as you like and position them anywhere.